# Django about get_context_data()

Tags: django

I was looking in django source-code to understand `super(ExampleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` and why I used it in my view:

```
class ExampleView(TemplateView):
    # ... atributes

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExampleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['key'] = 'value'

        return context
```

I've found:

```
class ContextMixin(object):
    """
    A default context mixin that passes the keyword arguments received by
    get_context_data as the template context.
    """

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if 'view' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['view'] = self
        return kwargs
```

I can't figure it out what that condition or `kwargs['view'] = self` does.

I've tried in my view to overwrite `get_context_data()` without that default condition:

```
class ExampleView(TemplateView):
    # .. atributes

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['key'] = 'value'

        return kwargs
```

and it worked the same as the first code I've written.

Comment: It simply adds the view as variable to the context, but you can easily leave it out

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what that 'view' variable does or what is used for. 
My intention is not to remove that kwargs['view'], I just simply want to understand what it does. 
By now, I understood that super() is like inheriting the method from ContentMixin or something like that. 

By the way, sorry for my bad grammar, english is not my native language.

Comment: It believe the view variable was only added a few versions ago. It does not do much, except that you can reference it from your template. Most people will not use this. I will provide an answer in few minutes to explain what is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 2 lines of code add the view as variable to the context if it was not already present. Most people never use this, but you could do something like this:

```
class SomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "something.html"
    title = "My list of books"

    def books(self):       #custom method
        return Book.objects.all()
```

And then in your template you could reference the books method and title attribute through the view variable:

```
<h1>{{ view.title }}</h1>
<ul>
  {% for book in view.books %}
    <li>{{ book }}</li>
  {% enfor %}
<ul>
```

Ah yes, and note that you don't even need a custom get_context_data() method in this case

Comment: It make sens now because kwargs['view'] is self, 
it's like referring to self.books value that is returned

Comment: That's correct, you got it! You could even override it and call it kwargs['self'] = self and then use self.books in your template